# How to code a cut operation with a "look and feel" like File Explorer

Tags: vb.net, listview

I need to code a cut operation with the same "Look & Feel" that i see if I perform the same operation in window explorer.

I use visual studio 2008 SP1 (professional and express) on win XP and 7

I have a form with two listview; each listview is in list view and each controls a folder and displays a list of files for that folder. Each row contains the filename with its own icon. the icon is extracted from the file itself and stored in an ImageList control.

[image: Folder display]

Cut and Paste operation works fine so my question is about "visual" part. In window explorer when selected files are cut (by contextual menu or CTRL-X) the icons changes to a disabled or no-color state. I wish to perform the same behaviour. I have found the following code:

```
ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled(lvwDocFiles.CreateGraphics, _
                               imgFileIcons.Images(Item.ImageKey), _
                               Item.Position.X, Item.Position.Y, _
                               lvwDocFiles.BackColor)
```

This code works fine and icons will be disabled.

[image: disabled icons]

But when I leave the listview to paste on the other listview icons visual state comes back normal.

So, how can I keep the icons disabled until operation has finished?

The code I'm using is a sub called either from mnuCut.Click or CTRL-X keypress

```
    With lvwDocFiles
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        ClipboardContent = Process.GetCurrentProcess.Id.ToString & STAR & _
                           (Convert.ToSByte(FilesCopy)).ToString & STAR & _
                           LinkType.ToString & STAR & _
                           FolderID.ToString & STAR & _
                           CodePlantArea.ToString & STAR & _
                           CodePlantUnit.ToString & STAR & _
                           CodedDocNumber & STAR & _
                           NumRev & STAR & _
                           CodeSender.ToString & STAR & _
                           FilesPath
        For Each Item As ListViewItem In .SelectedItems
            ClipboardContent = ClipboardContent & STAR & Item.Name & STAR & Item.Tag.ToString
            If Not FilesCopy Then
                'IconHeight = imgFileIcons.Images(Item.ImageKey).Height
                'IconWidth = imgFileIcons.Images(Item.ImageKey).Width
                ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled(lvwDocFiles.CreateGraphics, _
                                               imgFileIcons.Images(Item.ImageKey), Item.Position.X, _
                                               Item.Position.Y, lvwDocFiles.BackColor)
            End If
            Item = Nothing
        Next Item
        Try
            Dim LinkFileObject As String = ClipboardContent
            Dim LinkFileDataObject As New DataObject(LinkFileFormat.Name, LinkFileObject)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(LinkFileDataObject)
            LinkFileDataObject = Nothing
            LinkFileObject = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, CutOrCopy & " Files", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Oh boy. This is a good idea, but I'm afraid it's not going to be as simple as one would expect. There is, unfortunately, no built-in way to disable items in a ListView control, so you will have to do all of the drawing yourself. Your ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled code isn't working because you've put it somewhere other than the Paint event, so it's getting painted over by the standard drawing logic. A simple solution would be to just change the text color of the "disabled" items to `SystemColors.GrayText`, leaving the icon alone. Change it back to `SystemColors.WindowText` when re-enabled.

Comment: thanks Cody for your reply. Sorry for language mistake I'm Italian. Yes, the way to change the forecolor is good but it is "last chance" if I can not realize what I want. I will try to follow the paint event way as for your citation.

Comment: You will have to subclass the ListView control in order to custom-paint it. I'm not sure if you've done that or not. You will want to set the OwnerDraw property and override the OnDrawItem method. You didn't show how you're calling the code in context. (Your English in the question was pretty good—I didn't realize you were not a native speaker.)

Comment: Subclassing is actually over my VB skill so I need to investigate this way. Now I am thinking to store ina list of string the Item.Name of selected items and put in the paint event the ControlPaint...; next I can force the paint event to disable only items in the list

Comment: I have edited the post in which I have added the code. Another way should be as: save in the ImageList also the icons no-color and change the item icon as I need; this can be done when I store the icons extracted from file. I think this is a long way that needs some extra code.

Comment: For a true and faithful Explorer like operation, you would have to copy them to the clipboard then paint them disabled until a clipboard watcher you write sees Escape or they are pasted elsewhere. For the items you dont *have* to subclass it, but you would have to at least use OwnerDraw and draw them disabled in the DrawSubItem event until they are removed from the clipboard or the action is cancelled (esc).

Comment: Plutonix Thanks for your help. I will try the way you have indicated. I have to take into account, during OwnerDraw, also other types of operations that can be performed on listviews. One is Cut/Paste, but are also possible Copy/Paste, DEL and Edit (for renaming files). Clipboard watcher will be a couple of events (Cut_Started / Cut_Ended) raised when cut operation begins or ends. End of cut operation can be also a different items selection. I need to keep in mind all these situations and correctly coding.

Comment: The Clipboard is something that available system wide - any app can change it.  A Clipboard Monitor/Watcher is a Real Thing which will likely take you as long to write and the rest of the app.  Also, SO is not a message board.  When more than one person comments on your post, you need to use @Steve55 notation if you want someone to see your comment.  I only saw this because I left the tab open by accident

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix for clarification on how to reply to a comment. Now, for the clipboard I use a customized object (as you can see in the post at the code row ...LinkFileFormat.Name...). In this way clipboard contents will be available inside my application but not outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to illustrate the solution I found. The problem was, during a CUT/PASTE operation, visually obtain the same behavior that occurs when the same operation is performed in the file explorer window: display the icons of the items cut in disabled mode. Disabling icons is achieved with the statement:

```
ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled(......)
```

I originally put this statement in the sub who ran the cut operation but the first time that the listview was redesigned icons disabled comes back to their normal display.

Following @Plutonix comment I have realized that redesign of listview must be carried out manually. So at the time when the operation of the CUT starts I do two things:

1. I store the cut items in a collection CuttedItems; this will serve later in the redesign of listview because the selected items may not be more those cut
2. I activate the manual redesign with ListView1.OwnerDraw = True

The listview is in view LIST so I need only to code the ListView1.DrawItem event that you can see below:

```
Private Sub lvwDocFiles_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, _
             ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewItemEventArgs) _
        Handles lvwDocFiles.DrawItem
'
' Identify sender
'
    Dim lvw As ListView = DirectCast(sender, ListView)
'
' Clears background
'
    e.DrawBackground()
'
' Identify item image
'
    Dim itemImage As Image = e.Item.ImageList.Images(e.Item.ImageKey)
'
' Draw item selected or unselected
'
    If e.Item.Selected Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle( _
                 SystemBrushes.Highlight, _
                 New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X + itemImage.Width, _
                                e.Bounds.Y, _
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString(e.Item.Text, _
                                lvw.Font, lvw.Width).Width, _
                                e.Bounds.Height))

        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, lvw.Font, _
                              SystemBrushes.HighlightText, _
                              e.Bounds.X + itemImage.Width, _
                              e.Bounds.Y + 2)
    Else
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, lvw.Font, _
                              SystemBrushes.WindowText, _
                              e.Bounds.X + itemImage.Width, _
                              e.Bounds.Y + 2)
    End If
'
' Draw the image
'
    If CuttedItems IsNot Nothing Then
        If CuttedItems.Contains(e.Item) Then
            ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled(lvw.CreateGraphics, _
                                           itemImage, _
                                           e.Item.Position.X, _
                                           e.Item.Position.Y, _
                                           lvw.BackColor)
        Else
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(itemImage, _
                                 New PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))
        End If
    Else
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(itemImage, _
                             New PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))
    End If

End Sub
```

If the CUT operation is stopped (for example by pressing ESC key or starts an other operation like COPY/PASTE) ListView1.OwnerDraw will be set to False so the redesign of listview will be done as default.

Last note. In redesigning the text of the item I added 2 to e.Bounds.Y. It is a value found by tries. This is because changing OwnerDraw from FALSE to TRUE (and vice versa) I noticed that the text of the item did not stay at the same Y. I can not understand the reason why so I took this "empirical" solution.